# Variable POS TAG iMacros

Tags: image, tags, imacros, extract

```
TAG POS=1 TYPE=SPAN ATTR=TXT:Optionen
ONDOWNLOAD FOLDER=* FILE=+_{{!NOW:yyyymmdd_hhnnss}} WAIT=YES
TAG POS=36 TYPE=SPAN ATTR=TXT:Herunterladen
TAG POS=55 TYPE=I ATTR=TXT:

TAG POS=1 TYPE=SPAN ATTR=TXT:Optionen
ONDOWNLOAD FOLDER=* FILE=+_{{!NOW:yyyymmdd_hhnnss}} WAIT=YES
TAG POS=38 TYPE=SPAN ATTR=TXT:Herunterladen
TAG POS=55 TYPE=I ATTR=TXT:
```

I have that variable TAG POS in

```
TAG POS=36 TYPE=SPAN ATTR=TXT:Herunterladen
```

and want to build a loop. i dont know how i can solve that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the play loop option http://screencast.com/t/7I0rh5OBeL7 . You can also do this using JavaScript like below

```
for (var i=1;i<=5;i++)
{
iimPlay("CODE:TAG POS=1 TYPE=SPAN ATTR=TXT:Optionen");
iimPlay("CODE:ONDOWNLOAD FOLDER=* FILE=+_{{!NOW:yyyymmdd_hhnnss}} WAIT=YES");
iimPlay("CODE:TAG POS=38 TYPE=SPAN ATTR=TXT:Herunterladen");
iimPlay("CODE:TAG POS=55 TYPE=I ATTR=TXT:");
}
```